# Get field descriptor in Protocol Buffers

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Is there a way to get the field descriptor by using the given field number in protocol buffers? I know it exists for C++ (FindKnownExtensionsByNumber()) using reflection, however, I couldn't one for Java.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for an extension? Because the only thing that mentions that in your question is the C++ equivalent - whereas for a straight field, there's `Descriptor.findFieldByNumber`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Yes, I'm specifically looking for extensions.

Comment: Right. Well I've included both links in my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for [`Descriptor.findFieldByNumber`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.Descriptor#findFieldByNumber%28int%29). Note that will find a field by number, not an extension. For extensions, use [`ExtensionRegistry.findExtensionByNumber`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/ExtensionRegistry#findExtensionByNumber%28com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.Descriptor,%20int%29).

Comment: Yes, I saw that. However, it needs to parameters, extension type and number. Is there any method that just takes the extension number?

Comment: @pree: Not that I can see. To be honest it's a while since I've used the extensions mechanism in anger...